# I want to sum value of of third column based on other two columns value in google sheets and col1 and col2 contains multiple duplicate values

Tags: google-sheets, sum, logic, vlookup, countif

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MeiySJHI8OD84BPDOj_z57My-TXbs2ey4AOkQP3zug/edit?usp=sharing

I am sharing the link of sheet on which I want solution on that sheet also I have tried to explain you the question.

I have three columns I want sum of third col3 value based on first two column value

- if col1 = 2 and col2 = 40; Then I should get the sum  of all value in col3 in which col1 = 2 and col2 = 40
- if the col1 contains value of 2 and col2 contains 40 than sum of col3 value only those col3 value in which col1=2 and col2=40

so if any of the column value changes than sum of col3 also sum according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={"result"; INDEX(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A&" "&B2:B, A2:A&" "&B2:B, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B, 
 QUERY({A2:A&" "&B2:B, C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)), ))}
```

[image]

Comment: is their any way using which I can get that sum up value of third column can follow through untill the col1 and col2 value is matching like i have shown in my spreadsheet link pls check and help me out with it.

Comment: @new1 yes: see your sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Xlf.png

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is to use a pivot table, see inside your spreadsheet. If you want the total inside the original data, and take advantage of this simple solution, you can then recall the total by `GETPIVOTDATA`

Comment: yes sir i have done that but actually, I am searching for any formula using which i can do this and thanks for your time

Comment: to take advantage of this simple solution, you can then recall the total by `GETPIVOTDATA` (the pivot table has already been erased by somebody inside your spreadsheet)

Comment: the other advantage is that you do not have to sort your data

Comment: okk actually i don't want to create pivot table because it slow down the google sheet but thank you so much for your suggestion  and your time, it is one of the great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In cell K4 I entered

```
={"Result Col"; ArrayFormula(if(len(G5:G),if(match(G5:G&H5:H,G5:G&H5:H,0)+4=row(G5:G),sumif(G5:G&H5:H,G5:G&H5:H,I5:I),),))}
```

[image]

I used the same formula (with different range) in E1 (for what I assume to be your 'real' data).

See if that helps?

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help, your solution really worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it did !  Since you are new here, you may want to consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?